# Could you please explain this piece of code?

Tags: python

This has me a bit stumped. I know it iterates over an SQL result set, but a step by step explanation of what it does would be very good:

```
[{columns[index][0]:column for index, column in enumerate(value)}
    for value in db.cursor.fetchall()]
```

Comment: What part of it don't you understand? Do you know what `[a for b in c]` does? Do you know what `db.cursor.fetchall()` does? Do you know what `enumerate()` does? Be specific. As it is, this does nothing to show your work (if in fact you've made any effort to figure it out on your own).

Comment: Why not run it (ideally with a hardcoded example instead of the whole rest of the program) in a debugger or interactive visualizer so you can step through it one expression at a time? Then, if any of them aren't obvious to you, you'll know what to look up or ask about.

Comment: Or, if you don't even know how to do that, break it down into a sequence of separate statements, each assigning one intermediate expression to a temporary variable, and print out each temporary variable. That gives you the same information as the debugger or visualizer, just a bit more tediously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very concise list comprehension form, which is equivalent to the following:

```
res = []
for value in db.cursor.fetchall():
    pairs = []
    for index, column in enumerate(value):
        pairs.append((columns[index][0], column))
    d = dict(pairs)
    res.append(d)
```

The `res` list is equivalent to what you wrote above.

Comment: using a dict literal it would be  `res.append({columns[index][0]: column for index, column in enumerate(value)})`